# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting Based on a cell containing a specific formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a budget tracking sheet which automatically enters an account number using VLOOKUP from another sheet to match the contract that is being paid. This works perfect 95% of the time. The remaining 5% are instances when the contract is being paid from a different account than the default for one reason or another causing me to have to type over my formula to manually enter the account number. I'm looking for a way to conditionally format these cells. Something like: `=IF(E2:E<>"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""*"...`

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your formula contains a particular expression, in this case the word `VLOOKUP`. Put the follow custom function in the conditional formatting menu:

```
=isnumber(SEARCH("VLOOKUP",formulatext(A1)))
```

and this will highlight a cell if the cell `A1` contains a `vlookup` formula.

Feel free to change `"VLOOKUP"` with another formula text to make it more specific if you will.

[image]